# Git: How to sync working directory with a specific commit of a branch

Tags: git

I have converted a whole svn repository to GIT following [this](https://blokspeed.net/blog/2010/09/converting-from-subversion-to-git)

I have a full git repository with tags, branches and one master

(lets name the tags: tag1,tag2,tag3,... and the branches: branch1, branch2, branch3,...)

**I now added files (lets name them: file1, file2, file3,...) and commited them to master** (I see them in my working directory)

For the command :

```
git branch
```

the results are:

- master
- svn/branch1
- svn/branch2
- svn/branch3
- …

And if i do :

```
name@pc MINGW64 /path2GitRepo (master)
$ git checkout "svn/branch1"
```

the result is :

```
warning: refname 'svn/branch1' is ambiguous.
Switched to branch 'svn/branch1'
name@pc MINGW64 /path2GitRepo (svn/branch1)
```

But the files (file1, file2, file3,...) are still in my working directory.
How is this possible, i have commited the files to master not to branch1?

What would be the command to bring my working directory into the state of a specific commit of a branch?

I even deleted everything (except the .git folder) from my working directory and did :

```
git checkout-index -f -a
```

but the files are still there.

Edit:
Output of git show-ref:

```
2a1a9713eaedd9bc70f97568eae02752030515a9 refs/heads/master
8215eaf2d6049fc5f7375b0e7605af040860b4c8 refs/heads/svn/branch1
2a1a9713eaedd9bc70f97568eae02752030515a9 refs/heads/svn/branch2
a0886a261d934447ab089ad96a2838470176557c refs/heads/svn/branch3
fddda103d8fe4be3ba7cb929ec28cff0349b799d ...
8215eaf2d6049fc5f7375b0e7605af040860b4c8 refs/remotes/svn/branch1
a0886a261d934447ab089ad96a2838470176557c refs/remotes/svn/branch2
fddda103d8fe4be3ba7cb929ec28cff0349b799d refs/remotes/svn/branch3
2d3f16582b9bfba5ce491966624f31d59b417d03 ...
28fbcfcc64be5fcf0f7ea8e3e492ffee8a090e5c refs/tags/tag1
a68aeb93ea1a315323dc0ba2cd1d7d209469d33a refs/tags/tag2
56da5a8dcbef8b51ee748a2778e631e64ff69bda refs/tags/tag3
c3f879fdd5b401ced39135bd9d281d48f1dcc945 ...
```

Comment: Can you update the question with the output of  `git show-ref`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the `show-ref` output, seems like your branch name is `svn/branch1`

Probably this should not show any warning :

```
git checkout "svn/branch1"
```

Answer (score 1):

Please remove the double quotes around the branch name:

```
git checkout branch1
```

I don't know if the double quotes are necessarily wrong, but typically if you wanted to checkout a branch name which requires escaping you would instead use:

```
git checkout -- branch1
```

Comment: No, if i do "git checkout -- branch1"--> error: pathspec 'branch1' did not match any file(s) known to git

Comment: Does your `branch1` name possibly have whitespace or other hidden characters in it?